# How to clear session attributes after leaving my page/form in spring MVC?

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC.
Say I am on URL http://temp.com/page1
and I add some session attributes on GET and/or POST method.

Now when I am on the result page(after POST) on URL http://temp.com/page1Result, **I want the user to give the functionality to go back** to previous page using browser's back button or a back button/link on the second page **retaining all his previous data**.
 So, **I can not write `sessionStatus.setComplete()`** on second page's GET **as it would clear all the data** and user data will not be retained when using back button.

Ok no problem.
But now when I go to some other URL http://temp.com/someOtherPage, 
**I get those sesson attributes there as well** and I have no control on the code for this page/URL.

How can I prevent my session attributes from being there ?